# Filter out complex query with conditions using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to show the ID's that have the same ID and different stat value.

**Data**

```
ID              name    tag         stat
aaBBB1234:3716  apv     eertyyuiiio FALSE
aaBBB1234:3716  mps     rtuui       FALSE
aaBBB1234:3716  ty      fgggll1     TRUE
bbSSS2333:5000  teas    dexcv       FALSE
bbSSS2333:5000  llv     ieeve       FALSE
```

**Desired**

```
ID              name tag            stat
aaBBB1234:3716  apv  eertyyuiiio    FALSE
aaBBB1234:3716  mps  rtuui          FALSE
aaBBB1234:3716  ty   fgggll1        TRUE
```

**Doing**

```
# Filter the dataframe based on the desired condition
filtered_df = df[df['ID'].duplicated]]
```

This filters, however this needs to be expanded to specifically show the ID's that have the same ID and different stat value.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: This question is closed, but you could use: `df[df.groupby('ID')['stat'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]`

Comment: `df[df.groupby('ID')['stat'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]`